# What signature should my type's SelectMany method have?

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming, either

I have a simple `Either` type:

```
public class Left<L, R> : Either<L, R>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Left.ToString();
    }
    
    public Left(L left)
    {
        Left = left;
        IsLeft = true;
    }
}

public class Right<L, R> : Either<L, R>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Right.ToString();
    }
    
    public Right(R right)
    {
        Right = right;
        IsRight = true;
    }
}

public class Either<L, R>
{
    public bool IsLeft {get; protected set;}
    public bool IsRight {get; protected set;}
    
    public L Left {get; protected set;}
    public R Right {get; protected set;}
    
    public Either(L left)
    {
        Left = left;
        IsLeft = true;
    }
    
    public Either(R right)
    {
        Right = right;
        IsRight = true;
    }
    
    public Either()
    {
    }
}
```

I'd like to use this type with LINQ query syntax. I can implement `Select`, but I can't quite figure out the `SelectMany` method signature required. More accurately, this works:

```
var l = new Either<string, int>("no, this is a left");
var r = new Either<string, int>(2);
    
var ret5 =
    from x in l
    from y in r
    select y;

// returns ret5 as a Left, with the expected message
```

if I use the following implentation:

```
public static Either<L, RR> SelectMany<L, R, RR>(
    this Either<L, R> either,     // the source "collection"
    Func<R, Either<L, R>> g,      // why R here? why not L, R. can only be 1 argument. Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TCollection>> collectionSelector,
    Func<L, R, RR> f              // a transform that takes the contained items and converts to the transformed right
)
{
    if (either.IsLeft) return new Left<L, RR>(either.Left);
    
    var inner = g(either.Right);
    
    if (inner.IsLeft) return new Left<L, RR>(inner.Left);
    
    return new Right<L, RR>(f(inner.Left, inner.Right));
}
```

but I can't mentally correlate it with the documented signature (here from [Jon Skeet's Edulinq](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/27/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-9-selectmany/) post)

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectMany<TSource, TCollection, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TCollection>> collectionSelector,
    Func<TSource, TCollection, TResult> resultSelector)
```

Is there a general way of understanding what the signature of your `SelectMany` method should be for classes with multiple generic parameters?

EDIT: The [LaYumba library](https://github.com/la-yumba/functional-csharp-code/blob/02eac68e275286e5301ab3fe1cc611540d340d21/Examples/Chapter10/Transitions/Transition.cs) has a similar signature for a `Transition` example class so .. are the complete set of `SelectMany` overloads documented somewhere - including those for multi-parameter types?

EDIT: very delayed edit, but the [reference source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/dae14279dd0672adead5de00ac8f117dcf74c184/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs) details the signatures for `IEnumerable<>.SelectMany`, but doesn't tell you why they're needed. You can dig through the compiler code to get there but it's a painful journey.

Comment: I've read this a few times and it just doesn't make sense. How is it that `Either` is being used as if it was a collection? What is the supposed usage of `SelectMany`? Why is it called **Many** if it's selecting a single value? Are you trying to select left-most, if not center and otherwise right-most?

Comment: Either is a common feature of functional programming. It's often used to handle failure cases in a functional style, with failures expressed as a Left value, and successful returns as a Right. In detail, when they're processed by Select or SelectMany any Left values will just be propagated forward, and any Rights are processed with the specified function. This means we can write LINQ that's clean and expressive, without including a lot of `if (failed)` boilerplate. Check out "Functional Programming in C#" for a longer description.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Conceptually SelectMany is the Bind operation for a monad, but the C# devs didn't want to use the standard CS terminology for it because they thought it would confuse the programmers who didn't have experience with monads.  But the operation, and the say that the language uses it, isn't specific to sequences, it can be used for any type of monad.   (Whether or not you consider it a good idea, given that C# doesn't use generic terminology, is a separate question.)

Comment: :D I was trying to avoid the word monad. So @CamiloTerevinto in the example above you can think of l and r actually being operations that might fail. If either of them fail, the LINQ query doesn't invoke any following operations, and ends up returning the first failure.

Comment: To both of you, I'm very aware of the idea behind Either/Left/Right. I just don't see how that relates to `Select`**Many**. IMHO, if C# devs didn't go with the standard names, you shouldn't confuse the users of your library either. If I read a piece of code and saw a SelectMany (as in `var x = ...SelectMany(...)`), I will only ever expect Many results.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto If you understand that LINQ operates on monads, and isn't specific to just sequences (even though it chose names that indicates sequences was the primary motivation for writing it) then why the question?  If you know SelectMany, and the query syntax that uses it, doesn't actually need to be used on anything that's logically a sequence, then why ask that?  Now saying that it's not a good idea to use query syntax for generic monads is very different. That's a fine suggestion to make.  It doesn't make the question non-sensical though, just a bad idea for use in non-academic code.

Comment: @Servy Good point. I wasn't aware of the Bind operation and that it's named `SelectMany` in LINQ terminology, so that's what didn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested `SelectMany` overload only compiles because the only test case doesn't change the types. That is, in

```
var ret5 =
    from x in l
    from y in r
    select y;
```

both `l` and `r` have the same type: `Either<string, int>`. Thus, while being too constrained, the suggested `SelectMany` overload is actually enough to make the code compile. It's not flexible enough, however, to map between different types of Eithers.

## TL;DR;

The correct type of `SelectMany` is:

```
public static Either<L, RR> SelectMany<L, R, T, RR>(
    this Either<L, R> source,
    Func<R, Either<L, T>> k,
    Func<R, T, RR> s)
```

It may help to forget this particular overload for a little while, since it's a C#-specific weirdness that has no equivalent in other languages that I'm aware of (F# and Haskell).

## Bind

The standard `SelectMany` method in C# corresponds to what is usually known as *monadic bind*. For the `Either` type in the OP, it'd look like this:

```
public static Either<L, RR> SelectMany<L, R, RR>(
    this Either<L, R> source,
    Func<R, Either<L, RR>> selector)
{
    if (source.IsLeft)
        return new Left<L, RR>(source.Left);

    return selector(source.Right);
}
```

This overload is much easier to deal with, since it doesn't require that weird extra-step function that the other overload takes.

To be clear, however, the other overload is required to make query syntax light up, so I'll get back to that later.

If you can implement a `SelectMany` method like this one, the type forms a monad. Notice that it only maps the right-hand side, though. This may be easier to see if we also add a `Select` method.

## Functor

All monads are also [functors](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/03/22/functors). You can *always* implement `Select` if you have a lawful `SelectMany` (monadic bind), and the implementation is entirely automatable:

```
public static Either<L, RR> Select<L, R, RR>(
    this Either<L, R> source,
    Func<R, RR> selector)
{
    return source.SelectMany(r => new Right<L, RR>(selector(r)));
}
```

Notice that `Select` only maps `R` to `RR` while `L` stays fixed. *Either* is actually not just a single functor, but a family of functors - one for each `L`. For example, `Either<string, R>` gives rise to a different functor than `Either<int, R>`. Either is, however, a [bifunctor](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/12/24/bifunctors).

There's only one type to map: `R`.

## Query syntax

These two method are enough if you only need method call syntax, but if you also need query syntax, you're going to need that other `SelectMany` overload. As far as I can tell, if you already have `Select` and `SelectMany`, you can always(?) implement the other overload with the same nested lambda express:

```
public static Either<L, RR> SelectMany<L, R, T, RR>(
    this Either<L, R> source,
    Func<R, Either<L, T>> k,
    Func<R, T, RR> s)
{
    return source.SelectMany(x => k(x).Select(y => s(x, y)));
}
```

I actually copy-pasted that expression from a `SelectMany` method for an entirely different monad (State).

Notice again that `L` is fixed. It doesn't partake in any mappings, so it's as though it wasn't there. The 'intermediary' type is here called `T`.

## Monomorphism

The reason that the method suggested in the OP compiled is that the C# compiler is actually quite forgiving. If you make the generic types less generic than you have to, it still compiles.

For example, much to my surprise, I last year discovered that you can also use a more constrained `Select` method to implement [monomorphic functors](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2020/10/19/monomorphic-functors).

## Encapsulation

All this said, you should consider adding some encapsulation to the types in question. As the code stands, anyone can add a new class that inherits from `Either<L, R>` and behaves completely erratically.

You may, for example, instead consider a [Church-encoded Either](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/06/11/church-encoded-either).

Comment: While I chew this over, a small q: you say "Notice again that `R` is fixed ..."; should that be "`L` is fixed ..."?

Comment: @TimBarrass Yes, you're correct. I've fixed it now.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. What's the meaning of "intermediary type" here? Intuitively it's not just the right-type of the second Either.

Comment: I'm still not clear on how the linq query syntax parser chooses the form of SelectMany to call in general (experiment suggests it's the more complex version), and exactly how it forms the funcs to use for `k` and `s` here. But I think that's basically because I need to reread and think more.

Comment: @TimBarrass As far as I recall, the compiler can get by with `Select` as long as there's only one `from` in the query syntax expression. Once you add a second `from`, it'll go for the complicated `SelectMany` overload. To be clear, the compiler doesn't use the simpler `SelectMany` method for query syntax, but I recommend having that method around still, because it's simpler to use with method call syntax.

Answer (score 1):

> Func<R, Either<L, R>> g,      // why R here? why not L, R. can only be 1 argument.

Because in your implementation, you do:

> g(either.Right);

You could just as easily write it as:

```
Func<L, Either<L, R>> g,
```

and pass in:

```
g(either.Left);
```

Now of course this behaves very differently.  So it's simply a question of what behavior you want.  You want your `Either` to have the behavior of, "If the value of the outer either is left, use it and don't even construct the inner either, if the value of the outer either is right, get the inner's value and use that instead.  That means anytime you're getting the inner either's value (which is the function `g`) *the outer either is by definition a right either*.  If it wasn't, you'd have already returned the left value *and not even called `g`*.

(I'd like to take this opportunity to point out that using meaningful variables names here is part of the issue.  When you just call a variable `g` *nobody knows what that means* from just the name.  If you gave it a meaningful name it may have been clearer to you when it will be used, and why there is never a left value to pass to it in that situation.)

But you can write a different type using `SelectMany` that behaves differently.

In essence, the question comes down to *what do you want the type of `y` to be in this code*:

```
from x in l
from y in r
```

In your case, you want `y` to be the right value from `l`.  But you could just as easily write some other implementation that passes in *whatever it wants*.  You could pass in a `Tuple<L,R>` and let `x` in that query represent a pair of *both* values.  Now for your specific `Either`, the left value is known to not be populated, so it wouldn't actually be a good idea, but some other type of monad of a pair of values may need *both* values to generate a new value from a previous one.

Comment: Thanks Servy, am being very slow with this :) Just a quick note - when you say "You could just as easily write it as: `Func<R, Either<L, R>> g`" do you mean "`Func<L, Either<L, R>> g`" ?

Comment: @TimBarrass Yes